# Output .jpg file not created

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script here, which should create a set of 16 photos out of one. It additionally adds bleeds to the output jpg. My problem is that the script creates an output folder, but no jpg file inside it.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import os

# Directory path for the input images
input_directory_path = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ScriptTest\jpgRearrangment'

# Output directory path
output_directory = os.path.join(input_directory_path, 'output_with_bleeds_layout')
os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

# Output dimensions for the new .jpg with bleeds
output_width = 1270  # 127mm at 300 DPI
output_height = 1780  # 178mm at 300 DPI

# Bleed dimensions
top_bleed = 50  # 5mm at 300 DPI
bottom_bleed = 50  # 5mm at 300 DPI
left_bleed = 42  # 3.5mm at 300 DPI
right_bleed = 42  # 3.5mm at 300 DPI

# Calculate the dimensions of each individual photo with bleeds
photo_width = (output_width - left_bleed - right_bleed) // 4
photo_height = (output_height - top_bleed - bottom_bleed) // 4

# Function to add bleeds to an image and save it
def add_bleeds_and_save(input_image_path, output_image_path):
    img = Image.open(input_image_path)

    # Resize the original image to match the individual photo dimensions
    img = img.resize((photo_width, photo_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Create a new image with the desired dimensions and white background
    new_img = Image.new('RGB', (output_width, output_height), (255, 255, 255))

    # Calculate the position to paste the resized original image into the layout with bleeds
    x_offset = left_bleed
    y_offset = top_bleed

    # Paste the resized original image into the layout with bleeds
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            new_img.paste(img, (x_offset + j * photo_width, y_offset + i * photo_height))

    # Save the final image with bleeds
    new_img.save(output_image_path, 'JPEG')

# List all .jpg files in the input directory
jpg_files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_directory_path) if file.endswith('.jpg')]

# Process each .jpg file
for jpg_file in jpg_files:
    # Create an output image with bleeds and layout
    output_image_name = f'rearranged_with_bleeds_layout_{jpg_file}'
    output_image_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_image_name)
    add_bleeds_and_save(os.path.join(input_directory_path, jpg_file), output_image_path)

    print(f'Processed: {jpg_file} -> {output_image_name}')

print("All .jpg files rearranged with bleeds and layout and saved.")
```

What could be done, so that a jpg file is created here?

Comment: did you see if there's *anything* in jpg_files before you iterate it with for loop ?

Comment: Are you getting any _error_?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, after logging it shows me the following error:
ERROR - Error processing C:\Users\User\Desktop\ScriptTest\jpgRearrangment\TEST.jpg: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what i should have done, is what alexis said; Debugging my code. After including a log, an error said module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'. Turns out Pillow 10.0.0 removed ANTIALIAS. So unistalling Pillow 10.0.0 and getting Pillow 9.5.0 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

What can be done is to debug your code, in your environment. Here's one way this could go wrong: You are on Windows and the filenames end with ".JPG", not ".jpg". Print out `jpg_files` just before you enter the for-loop, and maybe you'll learn something.

Also, describe what happens when you run the script. Do you see a bunch of lines starting with "Processed: ", or does it go straight to "All .jpg files rearranged with bleeds and layout and saved."?